# Почему пишет, что маршрут неопределён, хотя он есть Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

routes.rb

```
resource :session, only: %i[new create destroy]
```

menu.html.erb

```
<li><%=  link_to 'Log OUT', session_path, data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?", turbolinks: false }, :class => "button" %> %></li>
```

Если заменить `link_to` на `button_to`, то всё работает чётко.

Если вручную прописать в `route` путь, то тоже работает чётко даже `link_to`

```
get '/session', to: 'sessions#destroy'
```

почему не хочет работать `destroy` c

```
resource :session, only: %i[new create destroy]
```

?

Пишет, что `No route matches [GET] "/session"`

это как я понимаю связано с Turbo?

Comment: А какая версия рельс?

Comment: у меня rails  7.0.7

Comment: В layout.html есть `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`? Проблема в том, что js не подключился правильно где-то